# the resource cannot be found asp.net mvc

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio

hi i already tried some solution available on stack overflow...some of them are configuring in routeconfig, going to project properties and creating a virtual directory. But none of them work for me. I've been working on this project and i don't know what happened suddenly. I've tried restarting laptop as well as visual studio . Please help it was working fine before

[image]

[image]

[image]

**UPDATE**:i have 2 controllers that are not working properly admin and account controller both have views as well as their corresponding controller

Comment: Do you have a route configured for the URL /admin/index in your RouteConfig?

Comment: @AlanBuchanan i have updated the question with routeconfig ss

Comment: Is it hitting your admin controller index method at all and blowing up when passing it off to the view? Can you set a breakpoint in there? Can you verify that _LayoutAdmin exists in your Views/Shared/ folder?

Comment: yes it exist @TravisActon

Comment: its not hitting the admin controller when i tried with breakpoint @TravisActon

Comment: I can't see how that URL would ever match one of your routes. I think that's where your problem is.

Comment: so where is the problem lying @AlanBuchanan

Comment: get rid of all your routes and use the default route a new project gives you, that should keep things simple and work with your controller actions

Comment: wow thank you so much @mxmissile your solution worked fine for me. you saved me a great trouble of recreating the project thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove all your existing routes and just use the default route:

```
routes.MapRoute(
  name: "Default",
  url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
  defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
);
```

This should keep things simple and should also work with your existing controller/actions.

Answer (score 0):

I think the issue is to do with your routes. Can you try an explicit route like the one below and check that it works?

```
routes.MapRoute(
  name: "AdminIndex",
  url: "admin/index",
  defaults: new { controller = "Admin", action = "Index" }
);
```

Comment: Where did you put this route in your RouteConfig? Put it at the top and re-compile if it wasn't already.

Comment: i have my breakpoint set at the index method of admin controller . the method is not getting a hit at all . the solution is still not working @alan

Comment: i have put it in routeconfig file and on the top as u said @alan

Answer (score 0):

Can you try adjusting your admin route like so:

```
 routes.MapRoute(
            "Admin",
            "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            new { action = "Index", controller = "Admin", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
);
```

Comment: when i hit admin or admin.index in the url , after trying your method it comes back to the home page within the home controller @travis